# How to install Subversion with python bindings on Mac

Tags: python, svn, homebrew

I'm doing:

```
$ brew install subversion --with-python
```

Yet, homebrew reports:

```
Warning: subversion: this formula has no --with-python option so it will be ignored!
```

It goes on to install subversion, as that was only a warning, but I need the Python bindings too.

I tried `--with-python` in other positions, but it does not make any difference.

Here's all the output:

```
Warning: subversion: this formula has no --with-python option so it will be ignored!
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/subversion-1.10.2.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/paul/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/cd34819a835db41e326680b8e94b4343ee0d98f68456b42c03fd1895c77b65c7--subversion-1.10.2.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring subversion-1.10.2.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
svntools have been installed to:
  /usr/local/opt/subversion/libexec

The perl bindings are located in various subdirectories of:
  /usr/local/opt/subversion/lib/perl5

If you wish to use the Ruby bindings you may need to add:
  /usr/local/lib/ruby
to your RUBYLIB.

Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/subversion/1.10.2: 244 files, 30.4MB
```

Other info: I'm on macOS 10.13.6. Homebrew was upgraded today (no upgrades pending). There's a info page https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/subversion that suggests that `--with-python` is a real option, but that's not something the install command agrees with. At least on my computer. Swig is install on my mac (v3.0.12) via brew.

Answer (score 0):

https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/subversion is out of date. The `--with-python` argument is not supported because the formula does the Python steps by default now.